# "vital" vs "crucial" which is stronger?

Tags: vocabulary

When I am talking about some skill which is very important, those two words:  "**vital**" and "**crucial**" are a kind of synonyms. But which is stronger?

**Update**
Here is the whole sentence:

> Free and independent thinking is a **vital** skill in any area. Moreover, in modern society it is **crucial**.

I am just thinking if I should actually use them vise versa...

Comment: Please include the dictionary definitions that you consulted.

Comment: I think this is probably subjective. To me "crucial" seems a bit stronger (in part because it can be used in phrases like "crucial moment"), but I would not at all be surprised to hear someone else say the reverse.

Comment: Merriam-Webster gives a total of eight senses for *vital* and six for *crucial*. Depending on which senses are being compared, *vital* carries more weight that *crucial*. Or they can be considered to be equivalent. The question needs to be clarified to provide specific senses and a specific context.

Comment: @JasonBassford I've updated the question with the context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling something *crucial* is not merely an emphatic way of saying that it is important or vital. The word *crucial* implies that there is something specific that depends on the thing that is said to be crucial. In other words, when one says that X is crucial, it has to be possible to elaborate that into **X is crucial for Y**; if Y is not made explicit it has to be made clear by the context. For the word to be apt, there has to be some crux, some juncture at which Y will go one way or another, depending on how X is. Saying that X is crucial for Y implies that X is decisive for how Y will go, rather than merely one of the many factors that influence Y.

For example, we call something a *crucial experiment*, if one possible result of it will definitely refute the theory under consideration, no matter how plausible it may have seemed before.

To say that in modern society free and independent thinking is crucial, thus leaves one wondering: crucial for what? Unless the context makes that clear, by specifying some dire consequence of its absence, one should look for some other word.